# How to Change more than one Value in If else Statement

Tags: excel, vba

How can i change more than one cell value in a IF-Else Statement?
My second code changes the value from Range(a & i) to 0.

This works:

```
If IsEmpty(ws.Range(a & i, b & i).Value) Then 
ElseIf Len(ws.Range(a & i)) > 2 Then Range(a & i).Value = 3
```

This does not work:

```
If IsEmpty(ws.Range(a & i, b & i).Value) Then 
ElseIf Len(ws.Range(a & i)) > 2 Then Range(a & i).Value = 3 And Range(b & i).Value = 8
```

EDIT:

For example i want to change my variables after 1 to 10 is done. I could just copy it over and over with changed variables but there must be an easier way.

```
For i = 1 To 10 

a = "BD" 
b = "BE"
c = "BG"
d = "BH"

Select Case True
 Case IsEmpty(Range(a & i)) = True:  
 Case Len(ws.Range(a & i)) > 2:  
        Range(a & i).Value = 3
        Range(b & i).Value = 8
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/if-then-else-statement

Comment: **One way**. Replace `And` with `:`. I am assuming that `a,b,i` are variables and you have an `End If` somewhere below?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Answer (score 1):

How about a `Select` statement? Easier to read and you can add multiple cases.

```
Select Case True
    Case Len(ws.Range(a & i)) > 2:
        Range(a & i).Value = 3
        Range(b & i).Value = 8

    Case <condition>:
        'action

    Case Else:
        'do nothing
End Select
```

Comment: Thank you. Works fine. Have one additonally question. Let's say i want to change my set of variables after running "For i = 1 To 10". How would i do that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you update your question with pseudo-code to show what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Please see my Edit.

Comment: First remove `= True` from `IsEmpty(Range(a & i)) = True`. It's not required. Second if I understood correctly what you're trying to achieve, I think it's best if you define a range, and then loop in both directions, horizontally and vertically. Scrap the letters and define indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Short and easy answer, like this:

```
If IsEmpty(ws.Range(a & i, b & i).Value) Then
ElseIf Len(ws.Range(a & i)) > 2 Then
    Range(a & i).Value = 3
    Range(b & i).Value = 8
End If
```

Thought if you are not doing anything on the first `If` there is no need to state it.

Comment: I would guess it is downvoted, because of the`ElseIf`what is confusing. I would nets and indent an  addidtional`If`, or combine the two criterias by`And`.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher the If structure is: `If ElseIf Else End If` there is nothing wrong with my code, just following the OP's code but without the error.

Comment: That's because there is no code for the first `If` and why I told to the OP that if there is no code, there is no need to use it.

Comment: There is no need, for  but you do ;) No reason for downvote for me, but could be improved.